# How to set the background view for header

Tags: react-native

```
  headerBackground:()=><View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:styles.primaryColor}}/>,
```

Iam in react naviation v4 (latest version to the date)
I trying add background Image in header using Imagebackground  component so i first tested out the view with the above code , if i run the above code navigation object inside the screen i get blank header

Comment: This above will not set a background image? Do you mean to set the background color?

Comment: the above code doesn't even render the color@SamuelG

Comment: Does it set the flex property? Is the issue not maybe the `styles.primaryColor` value?